# Adding spaces at the beginning of an array of chars

Tags: c++, arrays, char, addition, spaces

As in the title, I need to add user-specified number of spaces at the beginning of some word, using array of chars.  I need to do it in a function which takes my array as a parameter and returns it. Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void writeDownCharArray(char t[], int sizee)
{
    for (int i=0;i<sizee;i++)
    {
        cout<<t[i];
    }
}

char * addSpaces(char t[], int ammountOfSpaces)
{
    int numberOfCharacters=0;
    for (int i=0; t[i]!=NULL; i++){numberOfCharacters++;} //checking the amount of characters in my array
    char t2[numberOfCharacters+10];
    for (int i=0; i<ammountOfSpaces; i++) {t2[i]=' ';} //adding the sapces
    for (int i=ilosc;i<numberOfCharacters+ammountOfSpaces;i++) {t2[i]=t[i-ammountOfSpaces];} //filling my new array with characters from the previous one
    return t2;
}

int main()
{
    int numberOfSpaces;
    char t[10];
    cout << "Text some word: ";
    cin.getline(t,10);
    cout<<"How many spaces?: ";cin>>numberOfSpaces;
    writeDownCharArray(addSpaces(t, numberOfSpaces), HERE);
    return 0;
}
```

And now: How do I print it to the screen? If I say `cout<<addSpaces(t, numberOfSpaces);` it actually prints something strange to the screen (not numbers, just strange characters). And if I say `writeDownCharArray`, then what should I put in "HERE" place?

Comment: Why not use `std::string` and make life a lot easier for yourself?

Comment: There are no variable length arrays in current C++. You also should not return a local array from the funciton.

Comment: @EdHeal, I would imagine, this is a homework assignment.

Comment: You should not return reference to local variable (`t2`).

Comment: @Jarod42, OP is not returning the reference.

Comment: Im in a college, so there are some stupid requirements to do it in a char array

Comment: @SergeyA: nearly the same (t2 decays to pointer), OP got dangling pointer at the end.

Comment: @Jarod42, pointer is not nearly the same as the reference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The C++ way to solve this would be to use a [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) like

```
std::string add_spaces(const std::string & line, std::size_t number_of_spaces)
{
    std::string spaces(number_of_spaces, ' ');
    return spaces + line;
}
```

If you cannot use `std::string` then you are doing to have to deal with dynamic memory allocations and change

```
char t2[numberOfCharacters+10];
```

to

```
char * ts = new char[numberOfCharacters + ammountOfSpaces + 1];
```

We have to have this as Variable length arrays are not standard and trying to return a pointer to an array declared in a function will leave you with a dangling pointer and trying to use it is undefined behavior.

Since `new[]` was used in the function you will need to remember to call `delete[]` on the pointer that is returned after you are done with it.  This is another benefit of using a `std::string` as it takes care of itself.

As far as `writeDownCharArray` is concerned you do not need a size parameter as `cout` can handle null terminated c-strings.  You can simply have

```
void writeDownCharArray(char t[])
{
    cout<<t;
}
```

And then you main would look like

```
char * foo = addSpaces(t, numberOfSpaces);
writeDownCharArray(foo);
delete [] foo;
```

Comment: Without knowing the specific requirements for the class, I'd suggest giving the following signature `std::unique_ptr<char[]> addSpaces(char*, size_t)`.  It's OK to learn about dynamic memory management, but may as well start to learn it properly

Comment: Okay. Figured out, that maybe I won't get punished, if I do it using a string. So how do I call this function in main() then?

@Edit, awkay, got it. Thank you very much! Upvoted already

Comment: @Chad That is a good suggestion.  I keep forgetting `unique_pt` can be used that way.

Comment: Got one more question. Actually two. About add_spaces function parameters. First: why use "&" instead of "*", or nothing acutally (works), and second: why use size_t instead of int? (int works as well)

Comment: @Frynio since `line` is never modified and it can be expensive to pass a `std::string` it should be taken by `const &`.  This way no copy is made and you guarantee to the caller that you will not change the string.  I used `size_t` as that is what the size of the string is based on and `size_t` may be bigger than an `int`.